# iOS: How to add different frameworks for device and simulator in the same code xcode swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, simulator

I have a third party framework with different versions for simulator and real device.

***What I am doing:***
Right now I maintain two different targets for simulator and device respectively.
I need to add the framework to the target as well as to the embedded binaries section. I also have to import the header in the bridging header section as these are objc frameworks ( I have added swift compiler flags for each targets and import the necessary headers in bridging header section). If I add both frameworks in same target, it will give duplicate symbols error.

NB: I Don't have the source code for these frameworks. So I cannot build a universal framework and use.

***Question:*** ***How can I use these frameworks such that , without changing any code or settings, I should be able to run the code on simulator as well as on a real device?***

Comment: Doesn't the third party provide documentation on how to do this in the best way? Seems to be a rather strange to have one for the simulator and one for devices

Comment: You can just use two targets (one for simulator and other for device).

Comment: @rock88 That is what I am doing now.

Comment: @Scriptable This is a framework provided by google for video encryption and decryption. They don't provide any documentation. They gave one sample app which uses two different targets for device and sim.

Comment: @abhi1992 that is more than likely your best solution then. I cannot think of any other way and if Google knew of one they would of used it in the sample project

Answer (score 4):

I do this using an aggregate build target for the framework that runs a shell script. That script uses xcodebuild to create a framework for both the sim and the device, and then uses lipo to combine them into a single framework that can be included in any project, and work on both platforms. Here's a simplified version:

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}
FRAMEWORK_NAME="FrameworkName"
PROJECT_NAME="Framework"
CONFIG=$CONFIGURATION
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER="Build/${CONFIG}-universal"


# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO  BUILD_DIR="${BASE_BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BASE_BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "copying device framework"
cp -R "${BASE_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules (from iphonesimulator build) to the copied framework directory
echo "integrating sim framework"
cp -R "${BASE_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/"

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "lipo'ing files"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${BASE_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${BASE_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
mkdir -p "${PROJECT_DIR}/iOS Framework/"
rm -rf "${PROJECT_DIR}/iOS Framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}/iOS Framework"
```

Comment: This is a framework provided by google for video encryption and decryption. I don't have the source code for this framework. Your script will work only if you have the source code of the framework right?

Comment: For this particular solution, yes. However, you can use lipo directly to combine the sim and device frameworks into a single file, and use that (see step 4, above)